# iOS - How to detect whether a font is bold/black/heavy...?

Tags: ios, uifont

I want to detect the style(**bold** ,**heavy**, **black**) of a font. But I can just detect whether the font is bold.

```
BOOL isBold = (font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold)!=0;
```

There is no black or heavy trait in `UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits`.

A way is to check the font name whether contains 'black' or 'heavy' string, but this seems unreliable.

There is `UIFontWeightTrait`, but it's just for `UIFont systemFontOfSize: weight:`

And I want to create my custom font with a style if there is available these style.

Comment: BTW i answered if you want to check for bold/italic

Comment: Thanks, I already know how to detect bold/italic style as I mentioned in question.

Comment: ok do you want swift version of heavy/black usage?

Comment: I know how to achieve this in swift, but for others you may write a swift version.

Comment: Ok sure i ll do that

Comment: check my answer for swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if it's **Heavy** or **Black**:

```
NSString *fontUsage = font.fontDescriptor.fontAttributes[@"NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute"];
if ([fontUsage isEqualToString:@"CTFontHeavyUsage"]) {
    NSLog(@"It's Heavy");
}
else if ([fontUsage isEqualToString:@"CTFontBlackUsage"]) {
    NSLog(@"It's Black");
}
```

The list of other usage options are very simple, just put usage in format "CTFont......Usage", the list I tested are:

```
//CTFontUltraLightUsage,CTFontThinUsage,CTFontLightUsage,CTFontMediumUsage,CTFontDemiUsage
```

And How to create a font with usage, like heavy:

```
UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [[UIFontDescriptor alloc] initWithFontAttributes:@{@"NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute":@"CTFontHeavyUsage"}];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDescriptor size:17];
```

**Swift3** version for checking:

```
if let fontUsage = font.fontDescriptor.fontAttributes["NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute"] as? String {
    if fontUsage == "CTFontHeavyUsage" {
        print("It's Heavy")
    }
    else if fontUsage == "CTFontBlackUsage" {
        print("It's Black")
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want this, Is there a list of string like "CTFontBlackUsage"?  I also want to detect other style.

Comment: And how to create a custom font with black or other style?

Comment: Thank you, I forgot there is `initWithFontAttributes`.

Answer (score 1):

Swift Version for detecting Heavy/Black style of font

```
let fontUsage = font.fontDescriptor.fontAttributes["NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute"] as! String
if fontUsage == "CTFontHeavyUsage"{
    print("It is heavy")
}
else if fontUsage == "CTFontBlackUsage"{
    print("it's black")
}
```

and to create font with attributes:

```
let fontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor(fontAttributes: ["NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute" : "CTFontHeavyUsage"])
let font = UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptor, size: 17)
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you whether a font is bold or not:

```
var isBold = label.font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)
```

Here is some experiement: this gives you the correct answer even if the a bold font is set, or if you set the font's symbolicTraits manually to be bold:

[image]