# Add custom weight other than Bold in iOS Font descriptor in C# xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uifont, uifontdescriptor, uifontweighttrait

I have created a custom renderer as i wanted to use "SF Pro Display" font and using UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(size , weight) i get output as .SFUI-weight .Below is the code i used for custom font -

```
var descriptor = new UIFontDescriptor().CreateWithFamily("SF Pro Display");
            if ((attributes & FontAttributes.Bold) != 0)
        {
            var traits = (UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits) 0;
            traits = traits | UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits.Bold;

            descriptor = descriptor.CreateWithTraits(traits);
            Control.Font = UIFont.FromDescriptor(descriptor, (nfloat) label.FontSize);
            
        }
```

Here the problem is FontAttributes and UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits only provide options as Bold,Italic and i wanted Semibold ,Medium ,regular also .I have gone through some similar question but solution are in Swift and those in-build methods are not in C#.By above code i get output SFProDisplay-Bold similarly i want for SFProDisplay-Medium etc.

Went through this below links,
[How can I get weight of a UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686358/how-can-i-get-weight-of-a-uilabel)
[iOS - How to detect whether a font is bold/black/heavy...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974080/ios-how-to-detect-whether-a-font-is-bold-black-heavy)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I cannnot find **addingAttributes** method for **FontDescriptor**. So you may try the following code as an alternative:

```
var systemFont = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(24, UIFontWeight.Semibold);
var descriptor = systemFont.FontDescriptor.CreateWithFamily("SF Pro Display");
Control.Font = UIFont.FromDescriptor(descriptor, 24);
```

Hope it works for you.